# Cannot display image inside email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, mailer

I am trying to display my logo inside an email in my rails app. My image is located in assets/images and in the public folder. 
However my image seem to be never found by the app. How can I include my image in the email ?
Here's my layout mailer.html.erb where the image is included inside image_tag

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div style= "text-align: center;">
    <%= image_tag "quickbed_logo.png", style: "width: 200px;"%>
  </div>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the URL generated in the email?

Comment: it is generating /assets/quickbed_logo-5cdf68780205bd6d74901ec70cf2fd803831f6b3dee25b6e203c891e06302d1a.png which is not the right path but if I move my image one step higher in assets it still doesnt find it

Comment: Okay i think it is not working because the url generated is relative (it needs http://localhost:3333

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup `asset_host`?

In `development.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "http://localhost:3000"}
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

In `production.rb`

```
   config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://example.com"
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "http://example.com"}
   config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://example.com"
```

If this still doesn't work. In the code, you can try using `image_url`

```
<%= image_tag image_url "quickbed_logo.png", style: "width: 200px;"%>
```

Also, Did you enable `config.serve_static_assets`?

Comment: I did setup everything you mention but it is still not working

Comment: It's a config issue. `host` attribute is not being picked up by the helper. I have updated my answer to include more config changes.